# Why is "access review queues" at a different reputation threshold on MSO?

Tags: support, review, privileges

On the SE2.0 sites I use (Arqade mainly, but also Ask Ubuntu) the reputation threshold for the privilege "access review queues" is 500 reputation.

On Meta.SO this same reputation level  is at 2000 reputation.

Is there a reason for this inconsistency between the various sites?

Comment: Number of users likely to make the threshold?

Comment: Is that an automated thing or is this something that can be manually set on a per site basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in Meta Stack Overflow there is no review task like "First Posts", "Late Answers" which can be accessed with 500. In Meta Stack Overflow the review task which requires minimum reputation is "Suggested Edit" review and "Low Quality Posts" that can be accessed with [2000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).