# access review queues description inaccurate

Tags: bug, review

I first wondered why there were inconsistencies between sites with the reputation required to get access to review queues such as *first posts* and *late answers*.

500 on SO, 2000 on MSO.

There already is an answer to this question stating that [there are no *first posts* & *late answers* queues.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210166/why-is-access-review-queues-at-a-different-reputation-threshold-on-mso) on MSO. So because of this, that privilege would be superfluous. But it still exists, with an increased reputation requirement.

I found out that it got changes during [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191516/mso-review-queue-privileges-are-misleading).

This was the reasoning:

> Since those queues don't exist, this privilege is meaningless on Meta. We could just remove it here, but... Then it'd be really annoying to find and edit that wiki text.
>
> So I just raised it to 2000 here (the minimum required to access the Low Quality and Suggested Edit queues, which do exist), turned off notifications, and tweaked the wiki a bit. This should suffice to make it less confusing.

In my opinion this this is an ugly quick fix.

I find it confusing to have different reputation requirements, only to find out that the stated privilege does not really exist as described.

Wouldn't it be necessary to change the wording? This description simply does not apply:

> Access first posts and late answers review queues

[image]